# Facebook PHP Graph API not returning complete data

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm having an issue with Facebook's PHP SDK version 4.0.

I'm simply trying to retrieve the `insights/page_fans_city` metric via the Graph API:

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', 
    '/{my object}/insights/page_fans_city', 
    array('period' => 'lifetime'));

$response = $request->execute();
$client_graph_object = $response->getGraphObject();

print_r($client_graph_object);
```

However, no data is returned:

```
Facebook\GraphObject Object
(
[backingData:protected] => Array
    (
        [data] => Array
            (
            )

        [paging] => stdClass Object
            (
                [previous] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/...
                [next] => https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/...
            )

    )

)
```

I know that I have the Insights data that I'm requesting.  I can make the exact same request via the Graph Explorer:

**→ /v.2.0/{my object}/insights/page_fans_city?period=lifetime**

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "{my object}/insights/page_fans_city/lifetime", 
      "name": "page_fans_city", 
      "period": "lifetime", 
      "values": [
        {
          "value": {
            ...
          },
          "end_time": "2014-08-01T07:00:00+0000"
        },
        {
          "value": {
            ...
          },
          "end_time": "2014-08-02T07:00:00+0000"
        }
      ], 
      "title": "Lifetime Likes by City", 
      "description": "Lifetime: Aggregated Facebook location data, sorted by city, about the people who like your Page. (Unique Users)"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/..., 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/...
  }
}
```

I should note that I **am** receiving data if I omit the `page_fans_city` segment.  When it's omitted- I can view data for `page_fans_country` only.  Therefore

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', 
    '/{myobject}/insights/page_fans_country', 
    array('period' => 'lifetime'));
```

and

```
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', 
    '/{myobject}/insights', 
    array('period' => 'lifetime'));
```

**will** work for me ...

I suspect it's my Access token- but I'm not sure why that would be the case.  The app that I created only requires the `read_insights` permission.

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Thanks in advance,
Mike

Comment: It's definately a token issue.  In the Graph API Explorer- my ***App Token*** (for my blurred-out application name) does not return any results ([screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/RKhPBF2)).  If I use the drop down menu and change the application to the Graph API Explorer and generate an ***Access Token***- I can see all the data I need ([screenshot here](http://i.imgur.com/DIISVKd)).  I think the better question is- what do I need to do to my App Token to generate these results?

Answer (score 2):

It was a permissions issue.  **If** you ever see:

```
{
    "data": [
    ],
    ...
}
```

It's likely your access token does not have sufficient privileges to access the data you're requesting (that or there's simply no data).

My problem was that even though I was the Developer of the app **and** it was approved by Facebook (with the `manage_pages` and `read_insights` permissions)- I could not use an *app access token* to retrieve the insights data.

**I needed a user access token!**

I easily generated the user access token by manually creating a login flow per [Facebook's documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.1#login).  This [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token) was useful, too.

More info on Facebook tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens).

Hope this helps anyone who stumbles across this thread!

-Mike