# Facebook Insight API

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I need to be able to query the Facebook Insights API to get the page views for a clients Facebook Page. After reading through plenty of documentation, I've managed to make a call using a user access token to the API using this call:

```
dynamic result = client.Get("{clientspageid}/insights/page_views/");
```

This works fine, except for it only returns 3 days of results which always seems to start 2 days before the date of request. So for example, today is the 18th, but the results will show views for the 16th, 15th and 14th. I saw there was a parameter that can be added to specify the period, so I started using the following:

```
dynamic result = client.Get("{clientspageid}/insights/page_views?period=week/");
```

For some reason this returns no data. I've tried 'month' and 'lifetime' and get the same result. Any idea what I may be doing wrong and why the API seems to return on 3 days of results if a period is not specified? I need to return a weeks worth of results for my client.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "since" and "until", but only for a limited period (35 days) :

```
client.Get("{pageid}/insights/page_views?period=week&since=2016-01-25&until=2016-01-30")
```

See this post: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/

Answer (score 0):

How did you obtain a user access token? 
Have you tried with Graph api explorer first? 
There are 3 results but you can go "next" and see the next 3 results.

Comment: I used the method outlined in this link to obtain the token:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token.

Just noticed the 'next' link. I will see if that will bring back the results I require.