# Publishing videos to Facebook Page as Page - publish_stream and manage_pages permissions not working

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

Attempting to write a simple server-side Python script that posts videos to a Facebook page (not a personal page, but a sports team page that I have admin permissions for). The script works perfectly when uploading videos to my own personal FB page, and other FB pages that I created — but I keep getting this error:

```
OAuthError: [200] (#200) Subject does not have permission to post videos on this page
```

When attempting to post videos with the script to a page that I do have admin permission for, but I didn't create (pointing that out because it's a consistent difference in the oauth response I keep seeing, assuming maybe page creation has something to do with this?).

I have tried using [facepy](https://github.com/jgorset/facepy), which is a great Python library for Facebook, but so far no luck in resolving this issue.

I know that responses to questions related to this topic from a few years ago mention that:

> To publish to Page as User you need publish_stream permission granted
>   by User.
>
> To publish to Page as Page you need publish_stream and manage_pages
>   permissions granted by User and Page access_token which can be
>   retrieved from accounts connection of user.

But when creating a token for my app using Facebook's Graph API Explorer, all of these permission are enabled/checked off, every single one, but still the same permissions error.

Has anyone seen anything like this?

Comment: There is no permission named publish_stream. It was removed several years ago.

Comment: @WizKid Yup, as I mentioned, those suggestions are from a few years back — I'm not finding any recent posts that deal with this problem.

Comment: What API call are you making? What permission does the documentation for that API call say you need?

Comment: @WizKid Just making a simple POST request for uploading a video, works fine on my own page and other pages I've created. The Graph API Explorer allows you to generate access tokens and has all the permissions, user data and extended - I've been generating access tokens with all permissions granted.

Comment: That doesn't answer my question

Comment: @WizKid user_actions.video is the permission required for posting a video and is included in all of the permissions I enable when creating an access token. Does that work for you?

Comment: Are you using a page access token? Sounds like you might just be using a user access token.

Comment: @CBroe thanks man, yes that was it! Finally figured out their God-awful oAuth process for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution to this is here:

[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

For anyone trying to develop a strictly server-side app for automated video uploads via cron job to a page, carefully follow the steps outlined by donut's answer in the linked post.

Answer (score 0):

You need add this permission `publish_actions` in https://developers.facebook.com/apps/ in status and review items.

[image]