# How to post to facebook wall?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

All the google results that I have come across are for posting to someone else wall, which require creation of an App. our work requires less sophistication.

Basically the requirement is that when Admins are moderating reviews about our eCommerce products then they should have the option for posting that review to our own Facebook page.

From looking over the examples on google I feel like , those admins will be required to login, for which we need to share our fb credentials with a lot of people. This is not a good idea since some of them are really rouge.

Since we require posting to only one wall, for which we can store our crediantials in program only, which method can I use?

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/4820459

Using a permanent access token of a page administrator with the manage_pages permission you will be able to post on your Facebook page (and much more! so be careful how you manage it).

Then you should check the facebook graph Api https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/ for publishing the reviews.

Comment: I think there is no permanent accesstoken, Its for max 60 days only.?? Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: If you check the first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/4820459 it explains how to get a permanent access token for a page.

Test it later by pasting the token here: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken You should be able to read "Expires: never"