# Python Facebook upload video from external link

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, video, upload

I'm trying to upload a video to facebook from an external url. But I got error when I post it. I tried with local videos, and all works fine.

My simple code is :

```
answer = graph.post(
        path="597739293577402/videos",
        source='https://d3ldtt2c6t0t08.cloudfront.net/files/rhn4phpt3rh4u/2015/06/17/Z7EO2GVADLFBG6WVMKSD5IBOFI/main_OUTPUT.tmp.mp4',
    )
```

and my error is allways the same :

```
FacebookError: [6000] There was a problem uploading your video file. Please try again with another file.
```

I looked into the docs and found the parameter file_url but it still the same issue.

The format of the video is .mp4 so it should work.

Any idea ?

Apparently this error message is very confusing. It's the same message when you've an access_token who doesn't work. For example, I've this error message when I'm trying with my user access token and not if I use the Page access token.

Comment: Have you got the correct permissions for the page you are trying to upload too? You should be using a Page Access Token with the 'publish_pages' permission as documented [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/videos#Creating)

Comment: Yes I've ! I've check all the permissions. Right now I'm facing this issue with an local file which he said that I've no permission. But when I go to the graph tool, I put the correct permissions so I don't understand why it doesn't work. If I want to publish on a page, I need only my access_token with the permission on the page right ?

Comment: @DaschPyth all you need is your access_token to post to a page. Have you ever been able to successfully post a video? Have you checked your permissions on your app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never used `source`, I'm pretty sure that's for reading video data off their API. Instead, I use `file_url` in my payload when passing video file URLs to Facebook Graph API.

Refer to their [API doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video) for clarity on that...

It's also possible that the `tmp.mp4` file extension is causing you problems. I've had issues with valid video URLs with non-typical file extensions similar to that. Is it possible to alter that at the source so that the URL doesn't have the `tmp` ?

A typical payload pass using Requests module to their API that works for me might look something like this:

```
fburl = 'https://graph-video.facebook.com/v2.3/156588/videos?access_token='+str(access)
payload = {'name': '%s' %(videoName), 'description': '%s' %(videoDescription), 'file_url': '%s' %(videoUrl)}
flag = requests.post(fburl, data=payload).text
print flag
fb_res = json.loads(flag)
```

I would also highly recommend that you obtain a [permanent page access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token). It's the best way to mitigate the complexities of Facebook's oAuth process.

[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Comment: I'll put your answer as a good one. I managed to do it after the good access-token. You talk about a permanent page access token but I couldn't make it work after generating it. It's maybe my fault because Facebook oauth token is such a mess ! Thx by the way :)

Comment: @DaschPyth it's a multi-step process to procure the permanent page access, took me a few tries, but it does work if you use cURL instead of trying to do it using just Requests.