# How to query Facebook's graph-api?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, curl

I am using `PHP 5.3.8`, therefore I can't use the latest `Facebook SDK` which works only with `PHP 5.4.X.`

given a `url`, I'd like my server to tell if this is a facebook-like-page, or not.

Do I have to use OAuth? I used to use the graph-api, but now I get all weird errors. like no access-token provided, no authorization etc.

My code was using `cURL` with GET and accessed `https://graph.facebook.com/`.`urlencode("THE_PAGE_URL");`

I don't know if this is not an overkill to do a whole authorization from my server, and if so, to whom? I must say I am lost in the facebook documentation, frankly.

I tried this sample code from [Facebook](https://github.com/facebookarchive/facebook-php-sdk/blob/master/examples/example.php), which does not work at all.

Is there a simple way to get info about a public like-page from facebook?

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to make calls using the Facebook Graph API is with their [Graph API Explorer.](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/)

You have to be logged into your Facebook developer account to access it obviously, but it is really helpful if you're experimenting with making different calls to a Facebook page.

Regarding oAuth, I would also highly recommend that you obtain a [permanent page access token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token). It's the best way to mitigate the complexities of Facebook's oAuth process.

[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Comment: For now, the solution of using a "permanent token" (it's only for 2 months) is great for me, although I will need to renew it every now and then

Comment: @Ted If you follow those steps, you actually end up with a permanent access token that is just that: permanent. It doesn't expire :)