# Manage facebook ads api

Tags: facebook, facebook-ads-api, facebook-marketing-api

I have a task to integrate facebook marketing api with my web application.
The ultimate aim of my web application is provide a capability for my clients to manage ads without login in facebook. So, I'm asking a question: is it possible to create the only one account for all my clients and manage ads by this account? And if I can, does it right way to use fb marketing api?

Anyway, i would appreciate if someone could give me advice about which approach i should use in my case to manage ads without any client-side authorization.

Comment: Do these clients have their own Facebook ad account and apps and you want to manage ads for them or do you want to be a layer above the FB platform and run under your own ad account?

Comment: @bjeavons the seconde one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create ad accounts and run ads on Facebook for any number of clients for nearly any purpose* and not require them to log into Facebook. You can create ad campaigns and creative elements (graphics and links relevant to the client's products) using the Facebook Marketing API in your own ad accounts.

If you haven't seen it already, review the Facebook Marketing API getting started documentation and videos https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-apis

*You're still held to FB terms of service so be sure to review requirements for allowed ad content.

Comment: Thanks, and one more question: does it mean that i have to refresh my token every 60 days? I read [some](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token) questions about permanent access token, but it didn't work for me. Does it still possbile to get permanent token?

Comment: You should use long-lived access tokens to avoid having to refresh, yes. If your unable to get a long-lived token file a new question after running through the steps a couple more times https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Comment: Sorry to bother you again,but i'm kinda stuck. As I understand, the only account that I use to manage my ads should be the adiminstrator of business manager, is that correct? And if so, facebook docs says that one of approval criteria to get basic level access is "Login flow is clear to a user what permissions are being requested" which means that i eventually can't get such access level. But since i cannot perform any api calls as business manager through with development access - i cant' create any additional accounts for my users. Do you have any ideas how should I handle this? @bjeavons