# Post content as a page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to post a message to the wall of a business page. I follow the following [steps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/564979) and everything works fine except that I don't publish the message on the business wall as administrator.

```
graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token='xxx')
```

If I use `graph.put_wall_post(message='test')` I publish the text on my personal wall.

With the profile id of business page, `graph.put_wall_post(message='test', profile_id='5537xx')` I post something like `Me >  business page`

If I try to create the app using the business page, I get the following error:

```
Users not logged into their personal account cannot access developers.facebook.com
```

How can I post the message as a text post directly to my business page without error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get an `access-token` for a page. You are probably getting an access-token for your personal account.

As stated in the Graph API Docs, *[here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/access-tokens)* and [*here*](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/publishing)

> With the Pages API, people using your app can post to Facebook as a
>   Page (...) 
>   Before your app can make calls to read, update, or post to Pages you need to get a page access token. With this token you can view Page settings, make updates to page information and manage a Page.

Therefore, you basically should get the token corresponding to your page

> To get the Page access token for a single page call the API endpoint
>   /{page-id} using an user access token and asking for the field
>   access_token. You need the permission pages_show_list or manage_pages
>   to successfully execute this call.

And then make requests to post content, for instance, a message

> To post text to a Page's feed, provide a message parameter with the
>   text along with the Page ID:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/546349135390552/feed?message=Hello
```

On success, Graph API responds with JSON containing the Page

> ID and the ID for the post:
>
> {   "id": "546349135390552_1116689038356556" }

Read the links above and you'll have more information about it.