# Facebook Graph Api Android sharing image on a page

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share an image on a Facebook page of mine. But I couldn't figure out how to do this step by step. And couldn't find step by step guide for this.

This is my code to share an image on a page

```
Bundle params = new Bundle();

String nameText = name.getText().toString();
String tags = engine.implodeTags(tagsList);
String textText = text.getText().toString();
params.putString("caption", nameText + "\n\n" + textText + "\n\n" + tags);

params.putString("url", imagesList.get(mainImageSelected).getImageUrl());

params.putString("access_token", "{access token here}");

new GraphRequest(
    AccessToken.getCurrentAccessToken(),
    "/{page_id here}/photos",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST,
    new GraphRequest.Callback() {
        public void onCompleted(GraphResponse response) {
            if(response.getJSONObject()!=null) {
                Log.d("qwe", response.getJSONObject().toString());
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Shared on facebook", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
            else{
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Toast.makeText(activity, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
).executeAsync();
```

It works if I put access token by hand. I am getting access token here
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer .
But after some time this access token is not working any more. So I need to get new access token.

How to get PAGE access token from android itself? Via user login button of facebook sdk?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Please help.

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Answer (score 0):

Easily if you use facebook SDK to do that. read at here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android

Comment: I have tried using ShareDialog but with it you can only share image on your wall, but not on page you manage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get Permanent access token to share images on your Page. To get that you need to follow steps written here.
[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)