# Facebook Page Access Token with read_page_mailboxes permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to send private replies to page comments from my website. I am admin of the page and app.

Facebook's graph's api doc states following: "A Page access token with the read_page_mailboxes permission is required to create a message" but does not say, how to get the token with such permission.

I have tried tokens from "**me/accounts**", "**/{page_id}?fields=access_token**" and even generated 60 day access token from graph api explorer, but I get "OAuthException" with message "Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the object". Any ideas?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You need to ask the user for that permission during login, of course – like with any other permission.

It is the user (page admin), that grants this permission. Only after that is done, the page access token will “include” that permission.

Comment: When I go to app permissions, I have following permissions: THIS APP CAN: Send messages from Pages you manage

Comment: Go debug your user access token, and see what permissions it includes.

Comment: scope : "read_page_mailboxes" during login was sufficient, thanks

Answer (score 1):

To get a **permanent Page Access Token** with the additional permission 'read_page_mailboxes' you have to:

1. Generate a User Access Token with the permission 'read_page_mailboxes' for your app (use the Graph API Explorer) -> this generates a 24h User Access Token
2. Extend this User Access Token to "expires never" (using the Access Token Debugger)
3. Get a **permanent** Page Access Token with this User Access Token (using the Graph API Explorer on your Page Id)

See also:
[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/43570120#43570120)

Note: You don't need to request this permission through developers.facebook.com/apps - "App Review" - "Submission" - "Add Items"

Comment: When I try to create a user token from Developer Tools, there is no `read_page_mailboxes` available in the list