# Facebook private_replies returns (#200) The page does not have READ_PAGE_MAILBOXES or PAGES_MESSAGING permission

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messages

Dears,

I'm an admin on some facebook page, and I need to use "private_replies" on posts comments.
My **user token** has all permissions (including READ_PAGE_MAILBOXES and PAGES_MESSAGING) but when I try to use private replies on some comment I got this error:

> "message": "(#200) The page does not have READ_PAGE_MAILBOXES or
>   PAGES_MESSAGING permission."

My application still in development, and Facebook **rejected** the review submission for "Messenger" product in my application.

What is the required permissions to allow send "private_replies" in case I am the admin of both application and page, and how do I got those permissions ?

**Last Update:**

Hi, I followed this link:
[Facebook Page Access Token with read_page_mailboxes permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36787885/facebook-page-access-token-with-read-page-mailboxes-permission)

And used PHP code this time and I invoked the function "

> $helper->getLogUrl

" with permissions

> ['read_page_mailboxes, pages_messaging']

I can access all posts and comments on posts, but the I got the same error when try tom invoke:

> $fb->post('/49827_COMMENT_17616_49888_ID_3923669/private_replies',$params,$accessToken);

Error:
(#200) The page does not have READ_PAGE_MAILBOXES or PAGES_MESSAGING permission.

While I'm the admin of the page (admin but not owner) and the owner of the application, and while I can get all comments, why still unable to send private replies ?

Best regards

Comment: Debug the page token, and see what permissions it contains. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: It contains everything (including read_page_mailboxes and manage_pages and pages_messaging) .. and not expired yet

Comment: I don't think you can interact that way with a "live" page, as long as your app is still in development mode.

Comment: I have "email" and "default" approved items only, do I need "messenger" too ?
As I noted, Facebook rejected to approve my "messenger" item :-(

Comment: This has no direct connection to the Messenger API.

Comment: I changed the application status to "Live" and generated new token with "PAGES_MESSAGING" permission and still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you using a page token, or your user token?

Comment: User token...
Actually both stopped working after changing the application status to live.
I'm getting now (    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't ask me how but it works !

The page access token was not appear (and still) in my pages access token for my current application, while I can see all pages in my Facebook account, I guess because I become an admin on page after creating the application, it look like a bug !

I made new Facebook application, the pages access token become visible and I used the page token (not user token) to send private_replies and it works