# App access token, can't get user information

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-graph-api-v2.8

When I try to use the already generated access token, on this `https://graph.facebook.com/4921782178422?fields=id&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN`, it gives me this in response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "message": "Unsupported get request. Object with ID '4921782178422' does not exist, cannot be loaded due to missing permissions, or does not support this operation. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
  "type": "GraphMethodException",
  "code": 100,
  "fbtrace_id": "F2ot2MGcBBM"
   }
}
```

Facebook writes that all access tokens have permissions to public_profile, but i can't use the link above.
4921782178422 is a user id.

It works fine, when I use my own user access token, but that's only valid for 1 hour, and I need it longer than that.

I have followed these steps:
[facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

What do I do wrong?

Comment: is that YOUR user id? why not just use /me instead? did you read about extended access tokens in the facebook docs already?

Comment: It's not my user id, it is another ones, and extended access tokens? Can you send a link to that?

Comment: did that other user authorize your app? why not just use his access token? where did you get that id from? it looks like a global id, but you are not supposed to use those anymore. and you can´t get data of users who did not authorize your app, for obvious privacy reasons.

Comment: about tokens: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/