# How to deploy a script as an Facebook App

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, heroku

i have a python script "script.py" which do some processing on a **closed** group of Facebook which I am an admin of, the script does a routine check every 30 minutes.

Till now i was using Graph API explorer access token to authorize the script. Now i want to deploy this script on a server so that it runs automatically after every 30 minutes forever, i will be using heroku server to host my python script

I have read that i would want a access_token which don't expire, for that an app is needed and now i am confused with all the Facebook is using. I found this[facebook-permanent-page-access-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token) . On it's 3rd sub-step of step 1, it asks to "setup a website app", this is quite vague for me.

Can anyone explain how i can do this ?

Comment: When you get the access_token you can request facebook to give  long live access token. Is that what you want ?

Comment: You don't need to create a real "website app". You only need to create a Facebook App and use the app id and secret to follow through the steps you found.

Comment: @RajaSimon i think that would work, but how to get it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting the `access_token` you can make another request to fb with grant_type, client_id, client_secret, fb_exchange_token...

i.e )

```
ENDPOINT = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/oauth/access_token'
params = {
    'grant_type': 'fb_exchange_token',
    'client_id': app_id,
    'client_secret': client_secret,
    'fb_exchange_token': access_token
}
return requests.get(ENDPOINT, params=params).json()
```

Comment: I should use my app name instead of graph API explorer to het the access token right ?.
When i do this, i get an access token with very basic permissions, i need just one additional permission, when i request for the access token with additonal permissions, another pop-up says me to submit my app for an review, but you see i have just one script not an entire app. What should i do ?

Comment: One script or entire app is doesn't matter. If you want long live after getting the access_token make another call that I shown you.

Comment: If another submit app for review clearly indicating that permission needs approval.

Comment: @AshwaniGautam Did you get long access token ?

Comment: Yes, i got a long-live access token, which i have to refresh every 2 months.
I didn't submitted my app for review, because i do not intend to publish it and thus i was able to get access token with additional permissions.
Also is there a way we can also get initial access_token programmatically ?, today i just copy pasted the access_token from explorer tools