# Graph API v2.9 Access Token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to find how to generate an access token in the 2.9 graph API. Using their documentation doesn't seem to do much at all. It's very incomplete and hard to navigate

Comment: there is one specific page that you could just find by searching for "graph api access token" with google: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/

Comment: ....and here is another one: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

Comment: That's rubbish.  I don't think access tokens  will be here long term in web dev.

Comment: ...they are being used pretty much everywhere (since many years). what is rubbish about them?

Comment: They are inconvenient, no clear explanation about what they do off the bat.

Comment: i would say they are easy to handle and easy to understand. what explanation do you need? you authorize, get a token, use the token for api calls. that´s pretty much it.

Answer (score 0):

it is very simple...
1. Add the app on developer account fb
generate accesstoken he working about 2 hours https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer .
2. If you need a long token using generate with step 1 + app secret and client id and using url: https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/oauth/access_token?grant_type=fb_exchange_token&client_id={app_id}&client_secret={app_secret}&fb_exchange_token={short_lived_token}

I recently realized but still works. I using graph api v2.9 and using this documentation [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/28418469#28418469) 
I hope it will help you....