# Facebook - Private Replies - read_page_mailboxes permission missing

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to call

`/v2.9/{comment-id}/private_replies`

(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.9/object/private_replies) but always get the following error:

`(#200) Requires read_page_mailboxes permission to manage the object`

I'm using a test version of the app. The user submitting the comment is an administrator of the app. From my understanding, if the user is an administrator, the permissions wouldn't need to go through the review process just for testing/developing? read_page_mailboxes is not yet a confirmed permission for the app.

Any ideas what the problem could be?

Comment: You are correct. You don't need to get the permission approved by Facebook. You still need to ask the user for the permission and the user need to grant it.

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question: The problem in the end was that the access token didn't include the read_page_mailboxes permission. I had to manually create a page access token that includes it.

I initially created the token here: https://developers.facebook.com/apps/{APP-ID}/messenger/ but that doesn't seem to add the necessary permission.

See here on how to create a permanent page access token: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570120/769726

The permission doesn't need to be approved by Facebook while you're still in development.

Comment: thanks so much.  I was looking for this for the whole day.

Comment: actually for my app that was already live I didn't need to request the permission through https://developers.facebook.com/apps - "App Review" - "Submission" - "Add Items". It worked with the process described by @klemens: