# Facebook Pages: Posting to page via cron job

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm building a cron job script on my website to automatically post a "product of the day" from my server to my facebook page.

Unfortunately, there are some problems. It appears that I have to manually get a new page access_token and stay logged into my facebook account in order for the post to work.

Is there some way to automatically post to my facebook page once per day without having to manually get a new page access_token every day, or without having to be logged into facebook? How do I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, after search for hours, I came across the solution: [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

An amazing answer there! Sorry I couldn't find it before I posted the question.

Answer (score -1):

I think you need a FB app to get the right access_log token:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens

Comment: yes, I do have an App there as well.