# Access-token to Instagram graph API for backoffice standalone application

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, instagram, access-token

I am developing backoffice standalone application that gathers some data from facebook API and stores it in local DB for reporting purposes. Now I need to read some metrics from Instagram account (also via facebook graph API). I read this tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started , but as far as I understand it it is designed for web applications. Durig the registration process some screencasts are required that are irrelevant in my case.

I just need access token that will allow me to read metrics from my Instagram account that is connected to my facebook page. Does anyone know how to get it?

Comment: You don't need to submit permissions for review, if you are only going to use the app yourself. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/faq#faq_180362122361921

Comment: My application runs as cron process every night without any user interaction, so it needs kind of permanent access token. How can I get it?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post: [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/28418469#28418469)

This gives a pretty comprehensive walkthrough of how to get a short-lived, long-lived and permanent access token via the Graph API.

It may be a little late in your case but if you're still looking for a solution without building any front-end, then you could use the Graph API Explorer (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) to obtain a shorted-lived token, then follow the steps in the link above to acquire the permanent token, which can all be done via your own back-end. Be aware that the short-lived tokens give you between 1 and 2 hours of use before they need renewing.