# Upload photos to facebook app page using server-side script

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a server-side script, that should upload photo-albums to my facebook app page. How can script obtain page access token?

I know it's possible on client-side, when user logs in into facebook, and then asks for page access token using `me/accounts` query. But server-side script can not authorize as a user. So how this can be done?

---

UPDATE: I actually found how the same goal - uploading albums to app page from server-side script - can be achieved in another way, by manually creating never expired page token. It's described in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570120/4050723

But still I wonder, if this can be done programmaticaly, from script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to generate a User Token server side, it always needs user interaction. And you do need a User Token to get a Page Token.

You can create an Extended Page Token with an Extended User Token though, as you have found out already.

More information:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/