# I can't get events from a facebook page even with administrator rights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I had a working calendar that gets all events from a facebook page. Since about a week it stopped working. If I now test what is in the `events` object of that page, it is completely empty, but when I go to the actual page on Facebook, it's filled with events..?

Did Facebook change their api or policies all of a sudden? I can't find anything on that.

Why is this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/705097199526713/events?fields=owner,start_time,cover,description,name,place&limit=100&access_token=myaccesstoken
```

Giving me an empty result?

```
{
   "data": [

   ]
}
```

[But look here. Lots of events.](https://www.facebook.com/pg/youcanbeNOW/events/)

I even got a non expiring access token with full permissions, like `manage_pages` [following this post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

```
Access Token Info
App 2352352332: metz-nederland
User    2345325235: me
Page    705097199526713 : youCANbe
Valid   True
Scopes  read_insights, manage_pages, pages_show_list, public_profile
```

I hope somebody knows why this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Pages events API edges were deprecated in recent changes.

> Events API
>   Deprecated:
>   Endpoints that return data including /feed, /posts, /comments, and the RSVP list.

See here for more information:

https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2018/04/04/facebook-api-platform-product-changes/

Comment: In the introduction you can read:

"... apps currently accessing Events and Groups APIs will lose access today. Going forward, access to these APIs will require a formal app review and for apps using the Pages API, submission is required within 90 days once app review resumes or access will be removed."

App review is ATM suspended, but you should prepare your app to be reviewed if you need this information.

Comment: That's bad.. got this whole website functioning around Facebook events. There is no alternative? Only reviewing your app? I hope I can get it approved since it's not really an app on Facebook, I just use it to read data from Facebook and display on websites.

Comment: Yeah they don't have an alternative method right now. Once the review process is opened up again, you should be able to submit for permission to use the events edges again. It doesn't matter so much if its not a physical 'app' that you might use directly or not, just more of what you are doing with it.

Comment: And for more understanding, please check this:
https://techcrunch.com/2017/11/10/facebook-local/

Comment: @user249802 I have a suspicion they won't approve apps which post facebook events to the web. Why should they? They want you to use facebook, not a separate website. Do you post the fetched events to a website?

Comment: @Tom It's a calendar on a website from which people can attend an event that is shown in the calendar. It makes sense they want people to use Facebook but still.. it sucks :)

Comment: They might allow it. Who knows? It's worth a try. I just have a feeling they will say it's duplicating existing facebook functionality.