# Cannot get manage_pages publish_pages permission for admin of a Facebook app

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I'm trying to develop a Nodejs app that will automatically post images/videos to my page once/twice per day.

When using it in Development mode everything works fine, but after changing the app to Live mode, using the Graph API explorer I cannot get permissions to manage_pages and publish_pages. I'm asking for these permissions as the user with admin roles both at the page and the app.

I've read the documentation, and it seems to me that as an admin I should be able to get those permissions and get a page access token, but I can't.

Is there anyone that knows what's wrong?

Thank you!

Comment: _“that as an admin I should be able to get those permissions and get a page access token”_ - used to be this way, but has been changed, to prevent abuse. Now you can only ask people with a role in the app for un-reviewed permissions as long as the app is in dev mode, but as soon as you switch it live, you need to get them reviewed - in live mode, there is no such distinction any more between people with a role in the app, and normal users.

Comment: Hello CBroe, thanks for your answer. So I've got another problem, because I wanted my app to automatically post images/videos to my own page without any human interaction, and I've also read when starting the review process that Facebook won't approve the app if it is used to automatically post to a page. So do you know fi there's another way to accomplish my purpose? Thank you again!

Comment: Check https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v3.0#reference-publish_pages, it has examples of what you are and aren’t allowed to do. Auto-posting without the page owner’s consent or knowledge would not be allowed; getting stuff from your own CMS or sth like that published to your page automatically is a common use case however.

Comment: Hello CBroe, thank you for your answer. I know I need those permissions to publish (automatically or not) to my own page. But my concern is that if I start the review of my app (just a CLI Nodejs app without any option) Facebook will not validate it because that's what they warn you if you select the option when starting validation. So I'm really stuck here. Do you think I've to follow the validation procedure, or there's another way to get these permissions?

Comment: Chose “Other”, and describe what exactly your app will be doing in the extra text field … You will have to get your app reviewed, no other way.

Comment: Ok, perfect! Thank you very much for your answers! I'll try!

Comment: Hi, have you solved it? My manage_pages and publish_pages have passed review, now i'm stuck on INDIVIDUAL DEVELOPER VALIDATION... 2 weeks passed without news. I've sent my id card. The question now is... If i will validatet as individual dev, can i post to my page or i get limitation?

Answer (score 6):

To resolve this issue:

- Open your Facebook profile (the same one that has been added as an
  admin on the target facebook page).
- At the top-right of the page click on the down arrow and select
  "settings". From the left menu select "Business Integrations".
- Look for the app that is linked to the target page and click on the
  "View and edit" link.
- Ensure under the "Manage your Pages" -> "Pages" title the target
  facebook page is selected. Note: You might have to click on "See all
  Pages" to see all the pages linked to your facebook profile.
- Do the same by scrolling down to the "Show a list of the Pages you
  manage" title, you will need it later.
- Click on save.

Comment: Once you've done this though, what access token do you use and what API endpoint do you use to post to a page?

Answer (score 1):

your application will work fine if you stay in development mode.

If you need the application to publish with a cronjob or something similar and nothing else, you don't need to put your application live.

Also, you probably need to get a permanent token, that can be done by following that method : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token

Comment: After 2 days of messing around I have to thank you profusely. I had no idea I did not need the app to be in live mode for my usage. Turned it off love and voila suddenly everything works and I can get my access tokens.