# Facebook - Page access token creation methods that involve `manage_pages` now ask for Privacy Policy and other app details

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

I want to scrape comments, likes and posts for a Facebook page that I'm an Analyst in (I'm not the admin, I've been given the 'Analyst' role).

I'm using the code in https://github.com/minimaxir/facebook-page-post-scraper to scrape comments.

Apparantely, you can get likes, posts and reactions but you cannot retrieve the comments of a Facebook page without a Page Access Token.

so I went ahead and looked at the popular answer in the link [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Not sure if this used to be the case before, but if you follow the instructions in Step 1, substep 4, `In the pop-up, under the "Extended Permissions" tab, check "manage_pages".` For this to work, it is asking me to submit a request with many checkboxes asking me the purpose of needing this permission, and along with this, it is not letting me send a request review without having Privacy Policy URLs, App icons, User Guidelines and a VIDEO showing how this App will be used.. I literally just want to scrape comments from my own Facebook page where I'm been given an Analyst role that has lesser privileges than Administrator, and for this I was asked to create an App for it and set `Native or desktop app?` to `No` to ensure I don't get a `Bad Request` when I run my code.

I'd love it if you could give me any help in this direction.. I want a solution to how I could get Extended Permissions or follow the steps in the popular answer, or simply get Page Access Token without having to set Privacy Policy Guidelines, an App icon and a video showing a demonstration of something I can't understand.

Comment: You could perhaps leave your app in dev mode, that should enable you to grant the necessary permissions without review (for user accounts with a role in the app.) But then you are limited to relatively few calls, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#pages-4-24

Comment: It has always been in `dev` mode, it is still asking me to fill the other details regardless of what mode I'm in just to REQUEST the `manage_pages` this permission. By other details I mean, "Privacy Policy URLs, App icons, User Guidelines and a VIDEO showing how this App will be used"

Comment: @CBroe I have gotten a Page Token Access code, now I see a different error message at this website: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

and that error message is:
`
{

  "error": {

    "message": "(#10) To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook. To submit this 'Page Public Content Access' feature for review please read our documentation on reviewable features: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review.",

    "type": "OAuthException",

    "code": 10,

    "fbtrace_id": "BkGftkVf5k1"

  }

}`

Comment: With a page access token for the page in question you should not get that. Not sure if the analyst role is enough though to grant one with the necessary “capabilities” though; since manage_pages allows to perform administrative tasks regarding the page as well, you might need to get one from an actual page admin.