# Show my own facebook posts on my website

Tags: facebook

This should be easy, but after many days it is still not working. I just need to show my last facebook post on my website.
I already created an app and got the access token. Then I call:

https://graph.facebook.com/{PAGE_ID}/feed?access_token={TOKEN}

And I get this message:

'To use 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook'

I already sent the 'Page Public Content Access' for review and it gets rejected because I 'do not need Facebook login on my site'. They are right, I don't need people to login to Facebook on my site. I am the administrator of the app, I just need my posts, but I am still not able to get them. What else can I do?

I know they have plugins to embed a single post or my timeline on my site, but I need just the text of my last post so I can format it the way I want.

Comment: why not just use a page token instead, if it´s your page anyway? btw, hopefully you are not hardcoding a token client side, and implemented some caching so you don´t need to hit the api with every user?

Comment: How can I use a page token? I generated a page token in Graph Explorer and I can call me/feed, but if I use {PAGE_ID}/feed it still gives me the 'Page Public Content Access' error message. BTW, I am getting my page id from my page's source code, is there a better method for that? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I got it. I just call "me" to get my ID and then I call {MY_ID}/feed to get my posts, I will se if it works on my website

Comment: so you are talking about a user profile, not a page?

Comment: No, I only need my posts. I am following all the examples at [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token[/link] but when I get to the last step of getting a permanent access token it says 'Page Public Content Access', your use of this endpoint must be reviewed and approved by Facebook'

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard! Twitter took me minutes to do the same thing