# Accessing Facebook page posts

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

A client wishes to have their last Facebook post displayed on their homepage in their own branding and I am pulling my hair out!

In theory: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.1/page/feed allows an app to get the post with any access token, except the documentation and the API disagree and I need access public content permissions (applied for, but may not be approved before deadline).

The graph explorer allows me to get a page access token, but this expires after a few hours so not practical for their website.

I've reviewed the source of other plugins that do this, and we seem to be making the same request, but at no point do they seem to require application review since they are just getting public data.

Is this something new from Facebook, or am I missing a step?

Duplicate is not applicable since it still requires public content permissions.

Comment: _“page access token, but this expires after a few hours so not practical for their website”_ - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension

Comment: _“but at no point do they seem to require application review”_ - and you can determine this by just looking at code _how_ exactly …?

Comment: @Avi that duplicate isn’t very much applicable any more, even with the latest edit on the accepted answer - an app access token will only allow access to data of any page, if you submit for Public Page Content Access feature first, and that’s rather what they want to avoid here. For pages one has admin access to (directly, or by making a page admin log in to your app), a page access token is the way to go.

Comment: @CBroe I determined that not by looking at the code, but by reading the install instructions. Of course they could be out of date.  I see what you're saying about long lived tokens, but would rather not have to build in a maintenance routine to get a new token every 60 days.  Surely as an admin of a page there must be a way to say that an app can access my page details?

Comment: That way _is_ the page access token. The extended ones used to have no default expiry at all (but they would still expire if f.e. the page admin that granted them changed their account password), but now apparently Facebook has limited those to 60 days as well. I think they just want to prevent situations in which “long forgotten” apps could do damage years later, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It apparently is possible to create a permanent access token which solves the issue, a step by step guide can be found: [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)