# Facebook Graph API – Website fetching from Instagram Page – Screencast

Tags: web, facebook-graph-api, instagram

Currently using the old instagram API (deprecating in 2020) with instafeed.js it is easy to generate a blog type website fetching from the clients instagram website using an access_token. 
What I am trying to do is a website, only fetching the costumers posts from instagram displayed in a costume theme and using information from their facebook page for about, imprint and contact sections.

In a Nutshell what I am doing tih the old Instagram API

```
const feed = new Instafeed({
    // data,
    cget: auth.get,
    userId: auth.userId,
    clientId: auth.clientId,
    accessToken: auth.accessToken,
    clientSecret: auth.clientSecret,
    grant_type: auth.grant_type,
    redirect_uri: auth.redirect_uri,

    filter: function(image) {
        image.template = `<img src="${image.images.standard_resolution.url}}">`;
        return true; // so we don't exclude any images
    },
    template: '{{model.template}}',
});

feed.run();
```

– No logins required for the user visiting the website.
– Storing the access_token server side so every visiter can see the content from the API delivered on the website

Now with the Facebook Graph API; I did the following steps:

1. Linking the Costumers Instagram Business Account with his Facebook Page
2. Receiving the Admin rights for the facebook page
3. Creating a app on my Facebook Developer account

After this I am able to access data from facebook for testing (using the facebook explorer tool) but i can't access my data from instagram without doing a screencast.

How about using the Facebook Graph API for a costumer to fetch and display posts from their instagram feed or parts of it on their website? Is that no longer supported? And how can I record a screencast before I managed to even access this data to show how I plan to use it? Also because I am planning to store the token on the server, there is no interface to show on the screencast …

This explanation was very useful up until the screencast question.
https://bernardodiasdacruz.com/2018/03/05/fetching-from-instagram-using-facebook-graph-api/

I wasn't sure what to look for exactly, but I couldn't find an answer yet, that works and is still up-to-date.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the code you have tried already Philipp?

Comment: There is not an issue with the code. It is more a question of the setup with the Facebook Graph API and how to make a screencast of me usage of the API. I edit  the basic code block that I am using with the old Instagram API and instafeed.js in my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really is a hustle but the page you linked links again to some brilliant answer on [how to retrieve a permanent access token](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28418469/2199525).

It seems that actually all you need is that permanent access token and the connected Instagram business user ID following the official [Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started) guide.

If you have the permanent access token and this business user ID it seems you don't necessarily need to have your app reviewed to make it work. I don't even need to switch this app to "Live" for now. It's just working now.

Although I don't know if a may hit some quotas too early. But even this can easily be circumvented by just caching the API response into some database and let the API only be called hourly using a cron mechanism.