# end points available with new Instagram API basic

Tags: instagram-api

Have a basic question: is engagement rate (or data that can be used to calculate engagement rate- like #likes and # comments and #posts) available in the new Instagram API? And what about reach for a specific post?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

New Instagram API is using Facebook Graph API so you can reach posts, likes and comments and total number of them too over Facebook Graph API. Here you can get start from here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started.

If you follow these steps, you will able to figure out how it works.

Example of how to create app and get access_token : [create app and get access_token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token/28418469#28418469).