# Facebook Page Access Token to display ANY public fb page feeds

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm facing trouble in getting `access_token` which I need to use in displaying ANY facebook feed on the website.

I have followed the instructions here in that given link, [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token), but sadly not worked for me.

Below are my API details and my requirement is to display ANY facebook page posts via PHP code in my website.

`App ID: 1250216098473345
App Secret: c637f7640a185b8137e567295abe568f`

All I need is a non-expire access token to put in my code to display feeds.

`$userPosts = $fb->get('/ESPN/posts?fields=story,shares,likes.summary(true),comments.summary(true),full_picture,permalink_url,message,updated_time&limit=8', $accessToken);`

Tried given tokens to display data of public fb pages, but failed.

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1250216098473345&client_secret=c637f7640a185b8137e567295abe568f&grant_type=client_credentials`

`https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=1250216098473345&client_secret=c637f7640a185b8137e567295abe568f&grant_type=fb_exchange_token&fb_exchange_token=EAARxEJ5xJYEBAGXFLgn98sPHGqZA74pkipbxLPTCn0jx7vtZBipmoPcG7CYaBXqRol2IUhtAI9wlX4bpFOJ1oGWSEmucCzUYKQnCwH42BnCEZARuIgEPGR3r0ZCjvI343S5yLd1C8mPLQJHNKiAOskwhmP4FU0ZC6eEvVOZB1XnWYleZA639EntpCYedUNp9itjy9c2joZBZBqAZDZD`

Comment: "it does not work" is not sufficient, please add the result of your tests.

Comment: Go reset your app secret now before someone does really bad stuff with it.

Comment: @WizKid, thanks, I just reset the secret code :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't share you app secret publicly (hence the name).

There is no token that would allow you to display *any* Facebook page feed. Looking at your example call you most likely refer to pages you or your app users don't have a role in therefore you can apply for [Page Public Content Access](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review/feature/#reference-PAGES_ACCESS) feature which then would allow you to access public page's data/feeds.

The other option would be requesting manage_pages permission from a page admin for the specific page you want to access.

Comment: I want you to please take a look at these links, [https://smashballoondemo.com/?id=espn](https://smashballoondemo.com/?id=espn) and [https://www.juicer.io/](https://www.juicer.io/), they are showing **ANY** public FB page feeds. I want the same result to display feeds of FB pages but via PHP code.

Comment: Like explained in my answer this would require Page Public Content Access feature reviewed and approved.