# How to get permanent user token in facebook market api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

Using node sdk,

I need to fetch all ad insights in facebook. It's working fine with user token.

But I have a cron job that fetches data day by day. So I need to save a user token to access apis.

How to create a permanent access token for a user?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [facebook: permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token)

Comment: I have one doubt about that, is a page token enough to access ad insight APIs?

Comment: Yes it will work.

Comment: Few more doubts. 

1 - Data Access Expires in 3 months. (Is it based on when the user was last active?) 

2 - I need the account insights. Is it enough to save only one access token?
     For fetching account or ad insights, is there any relation with all page access tokens?

Comment: No it is based on when the token was issued.

Comment: Then how it become permanent? Is it need to reauthorize after 3 months?

Comment: There is no permanent access token, you will have to reauthorize it after every 3 months.

Comment: Okay. Thank you.