# Xamarin: how to retrieve and manage Facebook feed/posts and events easily?

Tags: facebook, xamarin, facebook-graph-api, xamarin.forms

I'm working on a basic **Xamarin.Forms app** for a client, which will contain some tabs like :

- a **company presentation** tab (address, phone number, mail, ...)
- a **news** tab, with data coming from a dedicated API, or posts from the company's Facebook page
- a tab allowing to **schedule an appointment**
- an **"about"** page tab

For the **news** tab, I would like to display informations coming from a **dedicated service**, or from my **client's Facebook page**. In both cases, I would like to display a "*date*", an "*image*" and a "*description*". If the data come from Facebook, I would like to display too the "*URL*" to redirect to the corresponding post.

To recover the Facebook feed of my client's page, I've created a new app on "***developers.facebook.com***", and I can recover the expected informations ("*created_time*", "*message*", "*id*", "*picture*") through the **API Graph Helper**, with calls to "***client_page/feed***" or "***client_page/posts***".

For the moment, I'm able to recover the data in my app with an URL like:
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/client_page/posts?fields=message%2Cmessage_tags%2Cpicture%2Cfull_picture%2Cpermalink_url%2Ccreated_time%2Cstory&access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN

But I have remarked that returned post that are events have not "message" field to display any information about this event.
I can recover it by calling "***client_page/events***", which return some other informations like "*id*", "*start_time*" or "*description*".

- ***I can't find a relation between the results of these 2 calls ("client_page/posts" and "client_page/events"): the returned id are not corresponding. Is there a way to find a relation between a "post" and an "event"?***
- ***Is there another way to recover these information, like an existing package that I could import in my project directly?***
- ***And finally, I haven't yet found a way to generate a "permanent" token to make these calls: must this be done on my client's page side or on the Facebook app side?***

I finally found a way to create a permanent Access Token in this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570120/1814666).

But with the generated token, I have no longer access to the events:

- with a call to "client_page/feed" I get the posts but no longer the events
- with a call to "client_page/events" I get an empty result

***Would you have any suggestion?***

Comment: this sounds like a FB Graph API question.  The fact that you're using Xamarin is irreleveant

Comment: Yes probably, but maybe some Xamarin developers have already meet a similar need, or could tell me if there is a library that can help me.

Comment: _“the returned id are not corresponding”_ - probably because they are different objects. There is the event itself, and then there is a timeline post about that event.

Comment: And regarding token lifetime, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/refreshing

Comment: Hi @CBroe, "events" and "posts" are different objects. But when I call the "client_page/posts" the "event" is returned as a "post" with some fields ("id", "creation_date", "picture" but without any text information as "message". If I call the the "client_page/events" I get the same event with the expected informations, like the related text in "description" field. I would like to be able to link these items, to add manually the missing informations like the description.