# ads_read permission neeeded for lead retrieval Facebook Graph Api

Tags: facebook-graph-api, permissions, ads, facebook-marketing-api

I have created an app in the facebook developers portal, connected it with a facebook page, where ad campaigns are running. The app has a webhook subscription with a backend endpoint, which means that every time someone submits an ad, the webhook gets triggered and so does the endpoint(post request for processing the lead)in my backend code running in a server.

For the new lead to be processed, we need to retrieve the ads data ( submitted by the user ) using the Facebook Graph API endpoint ( GET Request ):  `https://graph.facebook.com/v16.0/${leadId}/?access_token=${process.env.FACEBOOK_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN}`.

I have created successfully a facebook page acces token following the instructions here : [Facebook: Permanent Page Access Token?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17197970/facebook-permanent-page-access-token) .

The only permission I am missing at the moment is the ads_read permission. I have requested it multiple times explaining how my backend works, but every time it gets rejected.

Rejection message :

````
ads_read feedback


App rejected - Unable to verify use case experience in app
Developer Policy 1.9 - Build a quality product
We were unable to verify the use case outlined in your notes and screencast when we logged in to review your app.
To help resolve this issue, please consider the following recommendations:
Check that your app is fully developed and has correctly integrated the requested permission before re-submitting for review.
Provide correct test credentials to access your app in a test environment or development mode. Development mode allows your app to access permissions with limited test data for App Review.
If your app is in live mode, you must create a test app for your live app to create an App Review submission.
Please provide a correct test URL in your submission notes. This will enable us to access the testing environment of your app.
For more information, you can also view our App Review introduction video and App Review Rejection Guide.
Notes from your reviewer:
Hello Team,

We noticed that the use case is already valid. However, we were unable to test the usage of the permission due to lack of Instructions, and Test credentials in order for us to review the application.

Also, we noticed that the URL provided only leads to the Homepage. Kindly provide as well a URL that has login options for us to login.

Please re-submit accordingly and we will re-review your application. Thank you.

App Verification feedback
App rejected - Unable to approve permission request
Developer Policy 1.9 - Build a quality product
During review, we were unable to approve your submitted permission(s) or feature(s) and will not be able to approve the app for use.
To help resolve this issue, please review the following:
Make sure you have completed all development of your app.
Create a Test User and verify that you can use it to recreate the experience exactly as depicted in your screencast.
If you are able to reproduce this experience exactly as depicted in your screencast, verify that the testing instructions in your App Verification Details are correct and include the Test User’s email and password.
If your screencast is inaccurate but you are able to successfully test each of your requested permissions and features with the Test User, capture a new accurate screencast and upload it, verify that the testing instructions in your App Verification Details are correct, and include your Test User's email and password.
Resubmit for App Review.
For more information regarding this rejection, please visit our App Review Rejection Guide.
Notes from your reviewer:
Hello Team,

We noticed that the use case is already valid. However, we were unable to test the usage of the permission due to lack of Instructions, and Test credentials in order for us to review the application.

Also, we noticed that the URL provided only leads to the Homepage. Kindly provide as well a URL that has login options for us to login.

Please re-submit accordingly and we will re-review your application. Thank you

Business and access verification already done

Anyone knows the exact points that need to be mentioned in order for the permission to get approved? ```

Mostly the rejection messages are like the one above. Any solution to what I really need to include in my description when requesting ads_read permission ?
````